# How to properly expose a method inside a class in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

i'm using nativescript a week ago to create a little application.
I'm listing in a listview a serie of items and when an item is clicked i'm doing a request to a remote server to get the deatils. My intention is to grab the response and send it in the context to another page.
Here is my attempt

This function is triggered when the item is clicked

```
import { HotelDetailViewModel } from "../../shared/view-models/hotel-detail-view-model";
import navigationModule = require("../../shared/navigation");

export function selectHotel( args ) {
    let id = args.view.HotelId;
    var hotel = new HotelDetailViewModel();
    var rooms = hotel.getRooms( id );
    console.log(rooms);
    navigationModule.goToHotelDetail( rooms );
}
```

when I print rooms, i get nothing

```
import config = require("../config");
import requestor = require("../request");

export class HotelDetailViewModel {
    getRooms(id: number) {
        var url = config.apiUrl + "hotels/" + id;
        var rooms = [];
        requestor.get(url).then((response) => {
            response.hotel.room_types.forEach(room => {
                console.log(room.name);
                rooms.push({
                    name: room.name,
                    price: room.price,
                    id: room.id
                });
            });
        });
        return rooms;
    }
}
```

This file is printing the response correctly but, i'm getting nothing when i call getRooms in the upper snippet. Any idea?

I can figure out how to make it work.
If there is a better approach to achieve what i'm trying to do, please let me know how. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: your method seems to do an async call and this is why it returns an empty list. it wasn't filled at the time you passed it to console.log. try to return the promise itself and so delegate the handling of deferred data to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you `console.log` while the getRooms() is still doing the http request and the `rooms` variable is not pushed any items. Make the getRooms() return a promise like this:

```
export class HotelDetailViewModel {
    getRooms(id: number) {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            var url = config.apiUrl + "hotels/" + id;
            var rooms = [];
            requestor.get(url).then((response) => {
                response.hotel.room_types.forEach(room => {
                    console.log(room.name);
                    rooms.push({
                        name: room.name,
                        price: room.price,
                        id: room.id
                    });
                });
            });
            resolve();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the controller, you can

```
var hotel = new HotelDetailViewModel();
var rooms;
hotel.getRooms(id).then((result) => {
    console.log(r);
    rooms = result;
});
```

Comment: Hi, i'm using your approach but i got an error returning the promise.
cannot find de name 'T'. I added the d.ts file but the error persist

Comment: Oh sorry, that's what I used in my project, you just need to replace the "T" by "any". I will also update the answer.